# How can I delete a duplicate question?

Tags: support, voting, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

Here there is a "insightful" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330100/determining-if-a-number-is-either-a-multiple-of-ten-or-within-a-particular-set-o) about basic programming with 105 upvotes, and it has got 14 answers. But okay, [life is not fair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair) , so asking about the unfairness also gets 75 upvotes.

Unfortunately, I had asked a [similar question about the unfairness or arbitrariness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318145/arbitrary-behaviour-of-community-via-upvoting-low-quality-questions-and-downvoti), which turned out to be similar to yet another question about [fastest gun or fastest answerer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) which has 1200 upvotes.

So, without batting any eyes, users are willing to keep upvoting a question which has enough upvotes, but if accidentally, there is a duplicate question, everybody loses their mind and downvotes it. Since, life is not fair, that is okay.

**My question eventually got marked as a Duplicate. Since there is no value in that question, how do I delete it or at least mark it for deletion by moderators?**

[[ Who knows which way this new question will go, I guess the fastest gun knows ]]

Comment: What counts as, "enough"?  Why is your judgement more important than everybody else's?

Comment: @fbueckert , my opinion is immaterial, which is why I said "that is ok". Even if my opinion does not matter, I still have the right to my opinion and it is my opinion that the basic programming question is not worth 100+ upvotes ....

Comment: If you're worried about the reputation, you can flag it and ask for it to be disassociated with your account.

Comment: @publicstaticvoidmain , that sounds good ; Is "Disassociate" an option ? Or Do I have to flag it and type that in the comments ? I ask this because I see only 1 option "Moderator Intervention", whereas the answer below shows 5 options and I am wondering if there is some other "Disassociate" option which I am missing.

Comment: There's no standard option for it; you do have to use the "Moderator Intervention".

Comment: @Aethenosity , you are entitled to your opinion and your downvote , but I am not the only one who is concerned about "enough" upvotes. Check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201716/diminishing-returns-non-linear-reputation-from-great-answers , where OP is implicitly saying that there are Posts with more-than-enough votes and he is suggesting to limit it or make higher votes count less. Judging by the number of upvotes on that question, it is likely that many more folks also consider the concept of "enough" votes , maybe not in that exact wording.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if your question is a duplicate, generally you should not delete it. Duplicate questions can help users find the original question, just go to [this help center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for more information on if you should delete your questions after a long time of thinking.

If you still feel the post should be removed, if your question has not been answered yet, you can delete it using the 'delete' button under your question.

[image: Delete Button]

But if your question already has up-voted answers, you would need to flag it for "In need of moderator intervention" and explain why you think it should be deleted so moderators can check it out.

[image: Flag Button]

[image: Flag for moderator intervention]

Comment: There are upvoted answers.  You can't self-delete questions that have upvoted answers.

Comment: @fbueckert Still, the user shouldn't delete if it's a duplicate. Duplicates can still help.

Comment: Moderators most likely won't delete it unless there's a particularly compelling reason (like private data in the post).

Comment: @Dukeling True, but still, it could happen, who knows?

Comment: @Devealte [The standard policy for moderators is to decline such flags. ... Instead, you can have the post dissociated from your account.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)